# delphi twebbrowser setting attribute style for Element has no effect

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm setting attribute style for paragraph

IHTMLElement using

Elem.style.setAttribute('TEXT-ALIGN','center',0);

The style is being written in html, but TWebBrowser component does not center the text.

After saving and reopening the html document the text is shown in the center.

What should I do for style changing take into effect immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me (in D7, on Win7 64-bit with IE 11).

After clicking Button1, the WebBrowser displays "Some text" right-aligned, as expected.  After
clicking Button2, "some text" immediately displays center-aligned.  Hopefully,
a side-by-side comparison with your code will reveal what makes the difference.  If the following doesn't help, you might get a better answer if you add a SSCCE to your q.

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="adiv" style="text-align: right; color: Gray">Some text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code

```
procedure LoadWBFromString(WB : TWebBrowser; AString : String; out Doc2 : IHtmlDocument2);
var
  V : OleVariant;
begin
  WB.Navigate('about:blank');
  Doc2 := WB.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Doc2.clear;

  V := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  V[0] := AString;
  try
    Doc2.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
  finally
    Doc2.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Doc2 := Nil;
  LoadWBFromString(WebBrowser1, Memo1.Lines.Text, Doc2);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  E : IHtmlElement;
  Doc3 : IHtmlDocument3;
  S : String;
begin
  Doc2.QueryInterface(IHtmlDocument3, Doc3);
  Assert(Doc3 <> Nil);
  E := Doc3.GetElementByID('adiv');
  if E <> Nil then begin
    E.Style.SetAttribute('text-align', 'center', 0);
    S := E.Style.GetAttribute('text-align', 0);
    Caption := S;
  end;
end;
```

**Update:** The OP mentioned in a comment using IE6 on WinXP.  I tried by code in a
WinXP VM with IE8 installed and got the behaviour the OP described.  After calling
SetAttribute, "text-align: center" was added as the last attribute of the style
and was not acted upon, the text remaining right-aligned (and the original
"text-align: right", capitalised, appeared at the start of the style attribute list).

However, the following change resulted in the text being centered as desired.

```
  if E <> Nil then begin
    E.style.set_textalign('center');
//    E.style.setAttribute('text-align', 'center', 0);
//    S := E.Style.GetAttribute('text-align', 0);
//    Caption := S;
    Memo2.Lines.Text := Doc2.body.OuterHtml;
  end;
```

(I removed the code to get and use the text-align attribute because the
GetAttribute provoked an exception on WinXP/IE8.)

Presumably someone au fait with the details of the history of IE's DOM and rendering
could explain the reason for this difference between the behaviour of IE11 and IE6/8.

Comment: Same Result. The style is being written in html, but TWebBrowser component does not center the text.
In program runtime I read HTML as string and check if there is style attribute.


What should I do for style changing take into effect immediately?

Comment: Same Result. The style is being written in html, but TWebBrowser component does not center the text.
In program runtime I read HTML as string and check if there is style attribute.
In both cases there is the attribute with "center" value, but webbrowser does not apply this style immediately, but only after saving and reopening the html document.

Comment: Using     DocRange.execCommand('JustifyCenter', false, EmptyParam); affects immediately. But I prefer using style attribute.

Comment: I've created a completely new project with Memo1, Webbrowser1, Button1, Button2 components. Set onClick for buttons as You described. After Button1 click text is shown in webbrowser right aligned, but after button2 click tex remains right aligned, but value of the caption is "center"

Comment: then i added button3 with onClick "Memo1.Lines.Text:=Doc2.body.outerHTML;" and in memo1 received 
"<BODY><DIV id=adiv style="COLOR: gray; TEXT-ALIGN: right; TEXT-ALIGN: center">Some text</DIV></BODY>"

Comment: Then I added a command line before setting attribute in button2 event     "E.Style.removeAttribute('TEXT-ALIGN',  0); E.Style.SetAttribute('TEXT-ALIGN', 'center', 0);" but still there were 2 text-align attributes.

Comment: OS on my computer is WindowsXP, IE6 (I don't use IE that's why haven't upgrade it) DELPHIXE

Comment: Martyn, thanks. It works as it expected. OK. You may delete comments.

Comment: And where can I get additional information on set_textalign. I found nothing in msdn and in google.

Comment: I found it just by looking at the IHtmlStyle interface in MSHTML.Pas.  Also google found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx